# xbuild acting different when called from Xcode

Tags: c#, mono, xbuild

Our Xcode project needs to compile a few C# projects as a build phase. The xbuild command line call is acting different when run from Xcode instead of from Terminal

`xbuild /property:configuration=Mono Plug-ins/MyTestPlugIn.sln`

When run from Terminal, the copying of local assemblies for referenced projects occurs.
When run from Xcode, the copy does not happen which causes the compile to fail.

I'm guessing there must be some environment variable that is different, but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: how about if you use an absolute path instead of relative?

Comment: Try passing `/verbosity:diag` and compare the output between the two to see where they differ.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem.